# Preventing inlining of exported properties as constants w/ Google Closure Compiler

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Here's a minimal example of input JavaScript (generated by another language, but that's neither here nor there):

```
goog.provide('foo.bar');
foo.bar.baz = 42;
goog.exportSymbol('foo.bar.baz', foo.bar.baz);
foo.bar.quux = (function quux(){return foo.bar.baz;
});
goog.exportSymbol('foo.bar.quux', foo.bar.quux);
```

My expectation is that, because `foo.bar.baz` is not annotated as a constant, that it would not be treated as one.  Yet, advanced optimizations (both locally and via the [compiler service](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home)) inlines it anyway:

```
var d = this;
function f(g, e) {
  var b = g.split("."), a = d;
  b[0] in a || !a.execScript || a.execScript("var " + b[0]);
  for (var c;b.length && (c = b.shift());) {
    b.length || void 0 === e ? a = a[c] ? a[c] : a[c] = {} : a[c] = e;
  }
}
;f("foo.bar.baz", 42);
f("foo.bar.quux", function() {
  return 42;
});
```

Constant inlining is great, but the value in question isn't safe to inline, given that it's exported.  I've tried using `goog.exportProperty` and `@expose` annotations in addition to and instead of `goog.exportSymbol`, with no luck.

Help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update: `@expose` is now deprecated. Answer updated with new method.**

As you noted, `@const` has no impact on inlining. `@const` only means that the value doesn't change (is assigned/set only once).

`@nocollapse` was specifically created to prevent property collapsing. Given:

```
goog.provide('foo.bar');
/** @nocollapse */
foo.bar.baz = 42;
alert(foo.bar.baz);
```

The purpose of `@nocollapse` in this case is to prevent the compiler from collapsing the property to something like:

```
var a = 42;
alert(a);
```

However the compiler still knows from flow analysis that `foo.bar.baz` is assigned the integer `42` and never changed. Therefore it's going to just use the known values.

The only reliable way to prevent inlining is to export the property:

```
goog.provide('foo');
goog.provide('foo.bar');
foo.bar.baz = 42;
goog.exportProperty(foo.bar, 'baz', foo.bar.baz);
alert(foo.bar.baz);
```

There is a known (albeit small) need to stipulate to the compiler that renaming is safe, but inlining is not. See https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/detail?id=971

If you are not using closure library, the export would look like this:

```
var foo = {};
foo.bar = {};
/** @nocollapse */
foo.bar.baz = 42;
foo.bar['baz'] = foo.bar.baz;
alert(foo.bar.baz);
```

If your goal is to make sure `foo.bar.baz` isn't inlined OR renamed, then you would need either quoted properties and `@nocollapse`.

```
goog.provide('foo');
goog.provide('foo.bar');
/** @nocollapse */
foo.bar.baz = 42;
goog.exportProperty(foo.bar, 'baz', foo.bar.baz);
alert(foo.bar.baz);
```

If you are providing this namespace to others for use, then the best case is a combination of `@nocollapse` to prevent collapsing and allow external updating and `goog.exportSymbol`.

```
goog.provide('foo');
goog.provide('foo.bar');
/** @nocollapse */
foo.bar.baz = 42;
goog.exportSymbol('foo', foo);
goog.exportProperty(foo, 'bar', foo.bar);
goog.exportProperty(foo.bar, 'baz', foo.bar.baz); 

alert(foo.bar.baz);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I've already tried the `exportProperty` usage you suggest.  Trying it again just now via the compiler service (just to be sure), [the results are not desirable](https://gist.github.com/cemerick/7371885): `baz` is no longer present at all.  To be clear, the objective is to expose `baz` to users of the output that have not participated in the compilation, and allow their modifications of `baz` to be reflected in `quux`.

Comment: That's a different problem - and you can clearly see that `foo.bar.baz` was NOT inlined (but it was renamed). If you want to prevent renaming, you'll neeed to introduce either `@expose` annotations or use quoted properties. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Edited to include some working code that exports each symbol leading to the `@expose`d property.  Chad, this varies from your suggestion somewhat; `exportProperty` for `foo.bar` did not yield good results.  I'm curious why, but at this point, I'm happy to have something working.  Any final thoughts before I accept the answer?

Comment: I'm not sure what your "not good results" were, but the code you added looks equivalent to me.

Comment: Yup, you're right, I must have fat-fingered pasting your suggestion into the Compiler service UI the last time.  We'll likely always use `exportSymbol` anyway, just for the regularity of it (i.e. one call per "namespace" segment, done).  Thanks very much for your help. :-)